# Multiple YouTube video embedded autoplay sequence

Tags: javascript, video, youtube-api, jwplayer, autoplay

Hi there fellow SO users, I have started to develop a music archive site where users can share YouTube video's (Limited to music only).

I would like to incorporate a system which allows a list of these videos to be played automatically when the previous has finished.

The following code can be used to auto play a set array of videos, which will use one player rather than a list of them. In pseudo terms, the system I would like to create would be laid out in the following manner;

Player 1, Video 1

Player 2, Video 2

Player 3, Video 3

Player 4, Video 4

```
<div id="player1"></div>
<div id="player2"></div>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player1;
    var player2;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
            height: '350',
            width: '425',
            videoId: 'uO7kCUjUaUE',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
            height: '350',
            width: '425',
            videoId: 'Bt9tTEZjYG8'
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player2.playVideo();
        }
    }
</script>
```

An existing topic: http://goo.gl/5neM6Z touches on this question (script source), however extended ideas from the OP are not answered. Including the idea that when one video is played, all others are paused.

My questions are, would there be a simple way of modifying this code to achieve this or will a new script have to be written? Does this system exist elsewhere? Could JWPlayer be the solution?

Discussion and advice on this topic will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another example that does more of what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>4 Videos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="player1"></div>
    <div id="player2"></div>
    <div id="player3"></div>
    <div id="player4"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player1").setup({
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSE9Qk9wkig"
    });
    jwplayer("player2").setup({
        file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKPiIoLNMpA"
    });
    jwplayer("player3").setup({
        file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS5CfP8n_js"
    });
    jwplayer("player4").setup({
        file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZoO8QVMxkk"
    });
    jwplayer("player1").onComplete(function(){
        jwplayer("player2").play();
    });
    jwplayer("player2").onComplete(function(){
        jwplayer("player3").play();
    });
    jwplayer("player3").onComplete(function(){
        jwplayer("player4").play();
    });
    jwplayer("player4").onComplete(function(){
        jwplayer("player1").play();
    });
    jwplayer("player1").onPlay(function(){
        jwplayer("player2").stop();
        jwplayer("player3").stop();
        jwplayer("player4").stop();
    });
    jwplayer("player2").onPlay(function(){
        jwplayer("player1").stop();
        jwplayer("player3").stop();
        jwplayer("player4").stop();
    });
    jwplayer("player3").onPlay(function(){
        jwplayer("player1").stop();
        jwplayer("player2").stop();
        jwplayer("player4").stop();     
    });
    jwplayer("player4").onPlay(function(){
        jwplayer("player1").stop();
        jwplayer("player2").stop();
        jwplayer("player3").stop();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
jwplayer("player1").onComplete(function(){
    jwplayer("player2").play();
    jwplayer("player1").stop();
});
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, looks very good, I'll shorten this code for efficiency:
jwplayer("player1").onComplete(function(){
    jwplayer("player2").play();
    jwplayer("player1").stop();
});

Comment: I'd like to pick your brain once again if you'll allow it; I would like to look into an injection system where the video URL could be changed to URL stored in a database. PHP?

Comment: This is certainly possible, I would assume, but I have never attempted to do something like this before.

Answer (score 1):

In the JW Player, the default behavior for a playlist is to play each item automatically.

Would this possibly do what you want?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>4 Videos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="player1"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player1").setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSE9Qk9wkig"
          },{
            file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKPiIoLNMpA"
          },{
            file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS5CfP8n_js"
          },{
            file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZoO8QVMxkk"
          }
        ],
        primary: "flash"
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After implementing this idea, it does not involve the use of multiple players alongside the playlist function, I see you have more knowledge than me with JWPlayer, is this possible? or should I just insert values with "video name" etc into fields next to the player whenever the video changes? Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean you want 4 players on the page, and after the 1st player finishes, the next one starts, then the next one, then the next one?

Comment: That is correct. Either way the system you have presented seems to be a good alternative if this cannot be done. :)

Comment: You can do that, but what would happen if one of the other players is paused, and then another one is played? What do you want to happen here?

Comment: That sounds good, as I said in the question, all other players would need to be paused. :)

Comment: Ok, I will answer with another example.